# solve $4^{2x} = 8(4^x) - 15$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Having some trouble with this one. I'm getting stuck on trying to simplify it before I set each side to log, assuming that's what I have to do at all. I don't see any like bases so I'll have to use logarithms which I'm fairly competent at doing, just having trouble getting started and getting to a point that seems familiar to me as the layout of this question is new to me.

Comment: If you set $y = 4^x$, the equation becomes $y^2 = 8y-15$.  Can you solve for $y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that $4^{2x}=\left(4^x\right)^2,$ so this is a quadratic in $y:=4^x.$ The substitution gives
$$y^2=8y-15.$$
Solving gives $y=3$ or $y=5,$ so solving $x=\log_4y$ reveals $x=\log_43$ or $x=\log_45.$

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a quadratic equation with one unknown.
For
$4 ^{2x}-8(4) ^x+15=(4^x-3)(4^x-5)$
So the solution is
$4^x=3$ or $4^x=5$
Namely
$x=log_4 3$ or $x=log_4 5$